# k-Fold Cross-Validation across classes

Tags: cross-validation, train-test-split

Suppose I want to do *k*-fold cross-validation across a set of data points.  Each of these data points is a member of exactly one of *n* classes.  (For example, suppose each of the data points is a person and the class they belong to is their age in years.)  I want the distribution across classes of each of my *k* test sets to (as closely as possible) 'match' the distribution of classes across all the data points.  (And I want each data point to be in exactly one of the *k* test sets.)  The number of points in each of the *n* classes need not be a multiple of *k*.

Is there some well-known algorithm, or, better yet, Python library for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for **Stratified** K-Fold Cross Validation, which preserves the distribution of classes across folds of the data.

Scikit-learn has a [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html?highlight=stratified#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) function for Python users!